# How to play the next Song after first finished Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a Discord music Bot with discord.py, I'm new to Python.
I don't know how to let the Bot automatically play the next song. I tried many different things.
This is my current code for playing one song:

```
vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source=sound + ".mp3"))
await message.channel.send("Spiele nun " + str(sound) +"weiter")
```

With the above code I didn't get a problem.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `after` parameter of the `FFmpegPCMAudio` function. This parameter takes a callable as an argument and executes it when the current song is over.

- First, you have to create a song queue variable :

```py
song_queue = []
```

- Then, you'll have to change your `play()` function :

```
source = sound + '.mp3'
soung_queue.append(source)
if not vc.is_playing():
    vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source, after=lambda e: play_next(ctx))
    await ctx.send("Now playing...")
else:
    await ctx.send('Song queued')
```

- Finally, you'll have to create a `play_next()` function :

```py
import asyncio

def play_next(ctx, source):
    if len(self.song_queue) >= 1:
        del self.song_queue[0]
        vc = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source, after=lambda e: play_next(ctx))
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(ctx.send("No more songs in queue."), self.bot.loop)
```

You can name the `play_next()` function whatever you want.
If you want your bot to disconnect because it's been too long since it was playing sound, change the `play_next()` function to :

```py
import asyncio

def play_next(ctx, source):
    vc = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if len(self.song_queue) >= 1:
        del self.song_queue[0]
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source, after=lambda e: play_next(ctx))
    else:
        asyncio.sleep(90) #wait 1 minute and 30 seconds
        if not vc.is_playing():
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(vc.disconnect(ctx), self.bot.loop)
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(ctx.send("No more songs in queue."), self.bot.loop)
```

Comment: How you do send a text message back to the channel that there isn't anymore song in queue from the play_next function?

Comment: I've changed the `play_next()` function ;)

Comment: You're missing the event loop agreement for a few of your run_coroutine_threadsafe calls. Otherwise, this works perfectly. Thanks for the insight

Comment: @NepNep care to explain what you mean? I seem to have this error as well.