# How do I create a skip command for discord music bot in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I tried making a Discord bot with `discord.py`. I'm at the skip command section.
I have finished the other parts like play and queue commands.

I tried using the command `self.vc.stop()` to stop the song and skip to the next one but it didn't work, can anyone help me? Here is the detailed skip command I did:

```
class music_cog(commands.Cog):
   # all the stuff over here
   @commands.command(aliases=["continue"])
   async def skip(self, ctx):
       if self.vc != "":
           self.vc.stop()
           # plays the next song
           await self.play_music()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with what you are trying to do but it looks like [MrSpaar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62107725/13507154) might help you.

Depending on how you implemented `play_music()`, you should use the `after` argument of `vc.play()`. Here is the snippet that was provided:

```
import asyncio

def play_next(ctx, source):
    if len(self.song_queue) >= 1:
        del self.song_queue[0]
        vc = get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source, after=lambda e: play_next(ctx))
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(ctx.send("No more songs in queue."))
```

The key here is to use `skip()` as a lambda for `after` from what I understood.

Comment: Could you indicate if that helped solving the problem ?

Comment: Oh yeah forgot.
it didn't fix the problem for me but turns out I fixed the problem myself. or maybe cuz I didn't know how to do it correctly